# How to create combinations of key values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, dictionary, iterator

I have the following code working:

```
from itertools import product


dict = { 'Orange' : [ 2,4,8],
         'Banana' :  [8,16,32]
        }
names = list(dict.keys())        
fruits ={}
offset =0
for combination in product ( *dict.values()):
    fruits[f'set{offset}'] = [[names[0] ,combination[0]], [names[1],combination[1]]]
    offset+=1;
print (fruits)
```

Output:

```
{'set0': [['Orange', 2], ['Banana', 8]],
 'set1': [['Orange', 2], ['Banana', 16]], 
 'set2': [['Orange', 2], ['Banana', 32]],
 'set3': [['Orange', 4], ['Banana', 8]],
 'set4': [['Orange', 4], ['Banana', 16]],
 'set5': [['Orange', 4], ['Banana', 32]],
 'set6': [['Orange', 8], ['Banana', 8]], 
 'set7': [['Orange', 8], ['Banana', 16]], 
 'set8': [['Orange', 8], ['Banana', 32]]
}
```

Now when my dictionary increases to have more fruits and more values. I need to manually take care of that inside the for loop. How can I scale it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Iterate over items:
- for each item make all the combinations key and values
- store all those in a container specific for that key
- after the iteration finishes make combinations between all items in all containers.

from pprint import pprint
import itertools

```
d = {'Orange' : [ 2,4,8],
     'Banana' :  [8,16,32],
     'pear': [9,7,5]
      }

out = {}
for k,v in d.items():
#    pprint(list(itertools.product([k],v)))
    out[k] = itertools.product([k],v)

final = itertools.product(*out.values())
```

---

Comment: @IshanKumar - see edit. I think the first version had too many values.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
[[names[0] ,combination[0]], [names[1],combination[1]]]
```

with a `zip`:

```
[[name, count] for name, count in zip(names, combination)]
```

This will allow it to scale to lists of any length without you having to specify each index.